# From the Mac OS X command line, how can I insert a line after a certain marker line?

Tags: macos, command-line

I have an HTML file. One line is the file is white space followed by this text:

```
<!-- insert new downloads here -->
```

How can I insert a line of text after that line in the file, just from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

I did some sed research and this seems to work:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/<!-- insert new downloads here -->/<!-- insert new downloads here -->\
new content/' input.html
```

Comment: That command produces a backup file called `input.html-e`, which contains the old content, since the `-i` option takes the backup file extension as an argument.

Comment: If you add an empty extension to the `-i` option, that should work though, fixed in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '1
2
4' > test.txt
sed -i '' '/^2$/a\
3
' test.txt
```

(Edited to add `-i ''`)